# iOS: Can more than one person share an Apple developer account (as a team) on multiple Macs?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Or do we need to set up multiple accounts and link them together as a team?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I learned: The company account is the same price as the individual account:

http://developer.apple.com/programs/which-program/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as the Developer Account is a Company account, the lead can add multiple accounts as a **team**. As long as the Macs have their certificates that match the account, there shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: I don't think it has to be a Company account (or Enterprise).  One account has to be a paid account and the other accounts (free dev accounts) can be added into the team of the main account.

Comment: no, the account has to be a Company account vs. Individual account. Individual accounts cannot add team members. keywords "Company" and "Team".